# Showing all subcategories when click on main category in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to make function where when I click on main category name should load new page and display all subcategories if there are some.

So far I have this in my route

```
Route::get('/subcatView/{categoryId}', ['uses' => 'CategorySingleProducts@showSubCats']);
```

This is button in my index view where I click to load sub-cats

```
<a href="{{ URL::to( '/subcatView/' .  $category_menu->category_id) }}">{{ $category_menu['category_name'] }}></a>
```

This is from my controller

```
public function showSubCats($categoryId) {

      $subcats = SubCategories::where('category_id', '=', $categoryId)->first();
      return View::make('site.subcategory', [            
          'subcats' => $subcats
      ]); 
}
```

and subcategory blade

```
@foreach($subcats as $i => $subcategory)   

     <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default text-center">                              
               <div class="panel-heading">{{ $subcategory['sub_cat_name'] }}</div> 
                   <div class="panel-body min-h-230">
                           <img src="{{ $subcategory['sub_cat_image'] }}" alt="{{ $subcategory['sub_cat_name'] }}" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="panel-footer">
                       <div class="row">                                    
                          <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                    <a href="{{ URL::to( '/single/products/' .  $subcategory['sub_cat_id']) }} " class="btn btn-info view-more">View More</a>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
          </div>
@endforeach
```

In sub_category table I have column `category_id` which is equal to main category id.

When I open the page now I don't get anything for sub categories. no `sub_cat_name`, `sub_cat_image`... nothing. Just empty html style

Comment: Why don't `dd($subcats)` in `showSubCats` before return view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subcats query in the controller should request `get` (an array) not `first` (single object).

```
$subcats = SubCategories::where('category_id', '=', $categoryId)->get();
```

Comment: Thank's but I've got error: `BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()`

Comment: With `get();` it's working.. thank's `$subcats = SubCategories::where('category_id', '=', $categoryId)->get();`

Comment: Sorry I meant `get`

Comment: But really I think you should consider using Relationships for this kind of situations: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Will use them soon.. I still learning basics of Laravel and is a bit complex yet. Thank's again for help